# javax.xml.transform.Transformer: Unable to convert #UNKNOWN (java.util.ArrayList) to NodeList

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I need to send ArrayList to xsl-template as parameter. I try this way:

```
public ByteArrayOutputStream convertXml(InputStream inputStream, List<Certificate> userCertificates) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DOMResult outputTarget = new DOMResult();
templateKeeper.getClearNamespacesXslTemplate().newTransformer().transform(getXmlSource(inputStream), outputTarget);
    Transformer transformer = templateKeeper.getMortgageXslTemplate().newTransformer();
    transformer.setParameter("userCertificates", userCertificates);
    transformer.transform(new DOMSource(outputTarget.getNode()), new StreamResult(outputStream));
    return outputStream;
}
```

Inside xsl-template I have something like this:

```
<xsl:param name="userCertificates" />
...
<xsl:for-each select="$userCertificates">
...
</xsl:for-each>
```

Than, I see this error:

```
javax.xml.transform.Transformer: Unable to convert #UNKNOWN (java.util.ArrayList) to NodeList!
```

As I understand, ArrayList not converts to NodeList, and xslt can't iterate it inside xsl-template.

How to send ArrayList to xslt as iterable object?

Comment: In XSLT 1 pass in a sequence of nodes or NodeList, in XSLT 2 or 3 you can also have sequences of other types (e.g. all atomic types, nodes, in XSLT 3 maps and arrays).

Comment: I use xslt 1. Can you give me an example?

Comment: Unless there is some processor specific way to interact with a Java ArrayList and arbitrary Java objects like your `Certificate`s I think the only way is to find and create some XML representation of the Certificates and pass in a DOM NodeList of element nodes representing the certificate data.

Comment: The kinds of object you can pass to a transformer.setParameter() depend entirely on which JAXP implementation you are using. If the processor you're using doesn't allow an `ArrayList`, then you need to find out what it does allow.

Comment: Per `java.xml.Transformer` [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/Transformer.html#setParameter), value object of `setParameter()`: *The value object. This can be any valid Java object. It is up to the processor to provide the proper object coersion or to simply pass the object on for use in an extension.*